# Pass function in ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it posible to pass function into ng-model, for example

```
<input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" ng-model="createModel('email')" ng-change="addProperty(email,'email')" email required placeholder="Email">
```

ng-change is working fine, but `ng-model="createModel(email)"` is showing this error

```
> Expression 'createModel('email')' is non-assignable. Element: <input
> type="text" name="email"....
```

In controler i have :
// I just want to pass value for now

```
  $scope.createModel = function(modelName){
     console.log("Model name"+modelName);
  }
```

I saw examples on the internet that people doing this

Comment: Your createModel function does not return anything

Comment: i fail to see the purpose. You could just have a watch on the model in your controller. google for angularJS $watch to find out more https://www.google.de/search?q=angularjs+%24watch

Comment: @MichałDudak i put return "something" but I get same error

Comment: @AndreschSerj I dont want to $watch for model changes, I want my function to to something like this $scope.createModel = function(modelName){
     return modelName + currentDashboard
  } currentDashborad is variable in scope to, I wan to create dinamic models

Comment: why no $watch? is there a good reason for it?

Comment: @wickY26 I dont want to watch for model change, I want to change the model name dinamically .The thing is that I want to dynamically create models depending on drop down choice, for example models would be "model1" if value of drop down is 1, or model would be "model2" if drop down value is 2. I have this number stored in currentDashboard variable. i tried to to something like this in html ng-model="email{{currentDashboard}}" but i get syntax error here to.

Comment: @MarkuzShultz You could create your models dynamically in the callback function triggered by said watch, but that's what Anders Ekdahl already explained in his answer is guess.

Answer (score 26):

Looks like AngularJS added "getter" "setter" support in version 1.3

You can scroll to the bottom of their ngModel documentation page at:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

This allows you to specify a method instead of a variable in your ngModel attribute. The method should take an optional parameter. If an argument is passed it should store that value, if no argument is passed it should return a value.

You can see an example in another Stack Overflow answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28224980/984780

Answer (score 21):

It's not possible to pass a function to `ng-model` because Angular has to be able to set the value when the user changes the input value. You cannot tell Angular to instead call a function when the value is changed. What you can do is define a property on the scope with a getter and setter method, something like:

```
var email = 'test@test.com';
Object.defineProperty($scope, 'email', {
  get: function() {
    return email;
  },
  set: function(value) {
    email = value;
  }
});
```

But I'd say that you're better of creating a $watch for the property as that will be more familiar to other Angular devs.

EDIT:
To bind to different models depending on other values, you'd still bind to the same property in `ng-model`, but you can swap that out in a watch. Something like this:

```
var model1 = {
  value: 'hi'
};
var model2 = {
  value: 'hello'
};
$scope.model = model1;

$scope.checkboxValue = true;
$scope.$watch('checkboxValue', function(value) {
  if (value) {
    $scope.model = model1;
  } else {
    $scope.model = model2;
  }
});
```

And:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="model.value">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxValue">
```

That will change the value of your text input depending on if the checkbox is checked or not.

Comment: Thanks for an answer, the thing is that I want to dynamically create models depending on drop down choice, for example models would be "model1" if value of drop down is 1, or model would be "model2" if drop down value is 2. I have this number stored in currentDashboard variable. i tried to to something like this in html ng-model="email{{currentDashboard}}" but i get syntax error here to

Comment: Added an edit with an example that should lead you in the right direction.