# Why is my watcher giving me a "Infinite $digest Loop" error?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-watch

I'm having a weird issue with a watcher function:

```
$scope.$watch('builder.editItemForm.quantity',function(newValue,oldValue){
    if(newValue !== oldValue){
        if(newValue % 2 == 0){
            builder.editItemForm.quantity = newValue;
        } else {
            builder.editItemForm.quantity = oldValue;
        }
    }
});
```

I am getting this error as:

```
Error: $rootScope:infdig Infinite $digest Loop

10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [["builder.editItemForm.quantity;     newVal: 1; oldVal: undefined"],["builder.editItemForm.quantity; newVal: undefined; oldVal: 1"],["builder.editItemForm.quantity; newVal: 1; oldVal: undefined"],["builder.editItemForm.quantity; newVal: undefined; oldVal: 1"],["builder.editItemForm.quantity; newVal: 1; oldVal: undefined"]]

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%22builder.editItemForm.quantity;%20newVal:%201;%20oldVal:%20undefined%22%5D,%5B%22builder.editItemForm.quantity;%20newVal:%20undefined;%20oldVal:%201%22%5D,%5B%22builder.editItemForm.quantity;%20newVal:%201;%20oldVal:%20undefined%22%5D,%5B%22builder.editItemForm.quantity;%20newVal:%20undefined;%20oldVal:%201%22%5D,%5B%22builder.editItemForm.quantity;%20newVal:%201;%20oldVal:%20undefined%22%5D%5D
```

I am not sure how to avoid this. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: After removing watcher on "builder.editItemForm.quantity". I am getting error again... not sure on which watcher...

Answer (score 0):

since you are changing your value **builder.editItemForm.quantity** inside the watch that will again run digest cycle and watch always trigger when value changes . in your situation you are changing you value inside watch which will fall into infinite loop.

**Description**

This error occurs when the application's model becomes unstable and each $digest cycle triggers a state change and subsequent $digest cycle. Angular detects this situation and prevents an infinite loop from causing the browser to become unresponsive.

For example, the situation can occur by setting up a watch on a path and subsequently updating the same path when the value changes.

```
$scope.$watch('foo', function() {
  $scope.foo = $scope.foo + 1;
});
```

refer the doc
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig

Comment: first do not keep  builder.editItemForm.quantity = newValue; because the new value is already assigned you do not need to do it manually.it'll solve your problem.

Comment: I am trying to stop inputting odd numbers in text box of input type number. any better way to achieve that apart from watch?

Comment: you can create a filter .

Comment: use ng-model-options getter setter

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to go through watch and try to deregister watch after setting quantity. It would work for one time. 
Another thing is to use ng-model-options getterSetter, which will do the same as your watch event.

1) 
You can deregister watch event after some circumstances. 
In your controller:

```
$scope.$watch('updated', function(newValue,oldValue){
      $scope.stop();
});
$scope.stop = $scope.$watch('builder.editItemForm.quantity',function(newValue,oldValue){
        if(newValue !== oldValue){
            if(newValue % 2 == 0){
                builder.editItemForm.quantity = newValue;
                $scope.updated = true;
            }
            else
            {
                builder.editItemForm.quantity = oldValue;
                $scope.updated = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

$scope.$watch returns function which when is invoked, stop watching, which is called deregistering. It's still recurrency here, but may work.

Another more general solution is using ng-model-options getter and setter. 
in your view use:

```
ng-model="quantity" ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true; }"
```

and in controller [define getter and setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27918987/angularjs-ng-model-options-getter-setter):