# How to call a function from ng-model along with ng-model value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, meteor, angularjs-ng-model

I had a div with text field where I am capturing the value using ng-model .I want to call a function as I enter some date in the text field for some validation.So I want to call the function from ng-model.
So how can we have both ng-model value and also call a function from it..
How can we do it.

```
<input type="datetime" view="date" min-view="date" maxlength="10" 
 format="dd/MM/yyyy" ng-model="$ctrl.dateOfBirth" value = "{{dateOfBirth}}">
 </div>
```

I also want to call a function as `ng-model="$ctrl.check()"`since I want to check one validation while entering the value.
I tried `ng-model="$ctrl.dateOfBirth && $ctrl.check()"`

Its not working...can someone help

Comment: try `ng-model="$ctrl.dateOfBirth; $ctrl.check()"`, this works for events like onclick, might also work here.

Comment: Its not working

Comment: @KevinKloet angular_angular.js?hash=744f2a2…:12545 Error: [$compile:nonassign] Expression '$root.customerDetails.dateOfBirth;$ctrl.check()' used with directive 'datePicker' is non-assignable!


Giving above error

Comment: I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27918987/angularjs-ng-model-options-getter-setter/28224980#28224980

Answer (score 0):

If you want do validation for your datetime, it's better do it in right way, check the official example :

```
<script>
angular.module('dateInputExample', [])
 .controller('DateController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.example = {
     value: new Date(2013, 9, 22)
   };
 }]);
</script>
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="DateController as dateCtrl">
<label for="exampleInput">Pick a date in 2013:</label>
<input type="date" id="exampleInput" name="input" ng-model="example.value"
   placeholder="yyyy-MM-dd" min="2013-01-01" max="2013-12-31" required />
<div role="alert">
 <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.required">
     Required!</span>
 <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.date">
     Not a valid date!</span>
</div>
<tt>value = {{example.value | date: "yyyy-MM-dd"}}</tt><br/>
<tt>myForm.input.$valid = {{myForm.input.$valid}}</tt><br/>
<tt>myForm.input.$error = {{myForm.input.$error}}</tt><br/>
<tt>myForm.$valid = {{myForm.$valid}}</tt><br/>
<tt>myForm.$error.required = {{!!myForm.$error.required}}</tt><br/>
</form>
```

Comment: This is just one of the example..But in other case I just have text field where I have to have ng-model value and call function