# Add calculated ng-model to a json object by giving it a name

Tags: angularjs, json

I've got a strange question ...

In my view, I've got that

```
<td>
    <input ng-model="ca_mta_drive_min()"
           class="form-control"
           placeholder="Exemple : 2 500 000"
           ui-money-mask="0"
           disabled>
    </input>
</td>
```

In my controller, the value is calculated like this :

```
$scope.ca_mta_drive_min = function() {
    return $scope.etude.ca_pdm_d_mini
        * $scope.etude.foyer_zone
        * ((parseInt($scope.etude.ca_eomini) + parseInt($scope.etude.ca_eomaxi)) / 2)
        * $scope.etude.achat_internet
        * $scope.etude.ca_coefficient;
}
```

It works very well, but The problem is that i have to update the json object etude with the calculated value ca_mta_drive_min... Dont know if you see what i mean, i need to send this to the backend

To make you understand; i need my view to do somthing like that (notice its a value, not a function :

```
<td>
    <input ng-model="ca_mta_drive_min"
           class="form-control"
           placeholder="Exemple : 2 500 000"
           ui-money-mask="0"
           disabled>
    </input>
</td>
```

Because i have plenty of things in my object etude, but i dont know how to puch the calculated value into it ? I 've tried ng-change but it's not the real problem.

At the end, i send the etude object to the back end with $http, but how could i push the calculated values into my json named "etude" please ?

I wouldn't like to recall each functions before sending with $http, i could like an "additional ng-model " linked to my HTML INPUT that would update automatically.

Comment: Why you want to put `method` in `ng-model`, try method with `ng-change`, if  still you want to use then check this: [ng-model-options-getter-setter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27918987/angularjs-ng-model-options-getter-setter/28224980#28224980)

Comment: Thank you I'm trying ng-change but the input doesn't display anything, then.

Comment: Needs to put object using `ng-model` something like this:  `ng-model="xyz" ng-change="ca_mta_drive_min()"`

Comment: The problem is that the values that are changing are not the value of this INPUT but are coming from others INPUTS, so it does nothing.

Comment: ok then why you want to add method in that `input` element, when you want to call that method, then change value of `$scope.xyz`, should work. Or explain in detail.

Comment: I think i 've understood, i have to add ng-change to the others inputs, then they will start the calculation process, then update the disabled input , and his ng-model. sorry because its not easy to explain.

Comment: Thanks a lot it is working finally, i've placed my ng-model on others inputs, and into each function, i don't make a return any more, but i'm setting the variable like that for example : $scope.ca_mta_internet_change = function(){
  $scope.etude.ca_mta_internet = $scope.etude.foyer_zone * $scope.etude.achat_internet * ((parseInt($scope.etude.ca_eomini) + parseInt($scope.etude.ca_eomaxi))/2) * $scope.etude.ca_coefficient ; 
 }

Comment: And just for info, this is how my ng-changes looks like now(they are placed on 5 differents inputs) : ng-change="ca_mta_internet_change();ca_mta_drive_min_change();ca_mta_drive_max_change();ca_ca_faible_change();ca_ca_fort_change()" , it starts a lot of functions   and they are placed on the INPUTS who are supposed to start the change! (I was prefering the RETURN syntax who looks better, but can't use it in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to understand that if you use a function as the ng-model, then you need to use `ng-model-options="{ getterSetter:true }"`.  That way angular knows to call a getter/setter function.  The signature for that function also needs to follow the convention as:

#### getter/setter

```
var _privateVar = ...
$scope.getterSetterFunc = function( val ){ 
    if( val ) _privateVar = val
    else return _privateVar
}
```

... something along those lines.  The "gotchya" is that if you're trying to affect pull a value form that calculation in your getter/setter, you could trigger another digest cycle which calls the function, which calculates another value which creates an endless digest loop.  Angular hopefully will complain about this and kick you out of the loop with an error.

`ng-model-options` docs - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions#arguments

#### keep it simple

It would better to stick a normal var in for the `ng-model`, then use `ng-change` to call a calculation function on your controller. You might also want to stick some logic in there to prevent calculations in cases where the model hasn't changed.  I'm not sure what kind of safeties angular provides via `ng-change` but I would guess if you have the model value change and then flip back to its original value during a digest cycle, it will still kick off a change.

Comment: Thank you a lot, i 'll try. But the problem is that i need to write ng-change on several others HTML INPUTS at the same time for them to start the calculation function, and there are plenty of calculating functions based on theses others inputs.

Comment: Ok so I'm now using ng-change, but i have to start like 25 differents functions into it ! Do you think it is too much ? It won't look good in the view!

Comment: without seeing the full controller code and all the 25 calculations, I can't say.  I've have since moved away from using controllers to do hefty calculations in favor of using filters.  And my app has several dozen filters in it.  It just depends on your needs.  If it's read-only type calculations based on input, then a filter would probably work better.  If the calculations asynchronous or require a less-direct approach, then stick with your controller functions.