# How to know add element to an array if checkbox is checked and remove it if unchecked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, checkbox

Here is my code on HTML. I find it on google that I can use this.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-true-value="addTitle(cpPortfolioItem)" ng-false-value="removeTitle(cpPortfolioItem)">
```

Here is my angularJS controller.

```
$scope.addTitle = function(cpPortfolioItem){
        $scope.selectedTitles.push(cpPortfolioItem.id);
        console.log('$scope.selectedTitles', $scope.selectedTitles);
     };

     $scope.removeTitle = function(cpPortfolioItem){
        $scope.selectedTitles.splice(cpPortfolioItem.id,1);
        console.log('$scope.selectedTitles', $scope.selectedTitles);
     };
```

it doesn't work. I have logged it in console but I can see it neither push or splice the array. Maybe `ng-true-value` is not a valid directive? Anyone can help me on this? I will really appreciate it.

Comment: Use `ng-checked` attribute instead of true & false

Comment: how to tell if it is unchecked?

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22373562/pass-function-in-ng-model

Comment: `ng-checked` is an attribute and `ngChecked` is a boolean, returning true if it's checked, false if it isn't. You can use both ways ( from [API ngChecked](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked))

Answer (score 2):

Base on the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D) `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value` value are not event handlers.  These are the value set to the `model` when `input` is checked(`ng-true-value`) or unchecked(`ng-false-value`).

Use [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked) instead or use `ng-model` and attach `$watch` to the model.

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-change

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-change="titleChange()" ng-model="titleChanged">
```

In controller,

```
$scope.titleChanged = false;
$scope.titleChange = function() {
   if ($scope.titleChanged) {
      $scope.addTitle(cpPortfolioItem);
   } else {
      $scope.removeTitle(cpPortfolioItem);
   }
}
```

Working example:- 
http://jsfiddle.net/Shital_D/Lcumc3t7/10/

Comment: it doesn't work. it says ReferenceError: titleChanged is not defined

Comment: You need to add $scope.titleChanged in your controller.  And assigned true or false value to it.